# Words in sentences and their nearest neighbors in a lexicons

Tags: r

I have following data frame:

```
sent <- data.frame(words = c("just right size", "size love quality", "laptop worth price", "price amazing user",
                         "explanation complex what", "easy set", "product best buy", "buy priceless when"), user = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Sent data frame resulted into:

```
words                          user
just right size                 1
size love quality               2
laptop worth price              3
price amazing user              4
explanation complex what        5
easy set                        6
product best buy                7
buy priceless when              8
```

I need to remove word at the begining of following sentence which is the same as a word at the end of previous sentece.

I mean eg. we have a sentences "just right **size**" and "**size** love quality", so I need to remove word **size** at the second user possition.
Then sentences "laptop worth **price**" and "**price** amazing user", so I need to remove word **price** at fourth user possition.

Can anyone help me, I'll appreciate any of your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the "first" and "last" word from the "words" column for the succeeding row and the current row using `sub`.  If the words are the same, remove the first word from the succeeding row or else keep it as such (`ifelse(...)`)

```
w1 <- sub(' .*', '', sent$words[-1])
w2 <- sub('.* ', '', sent$words[-nrow(sent)])
sent$words <- as.character(sent$words)
sent$words
#[1] "just right size"          "size love quality"       
#[3] "laptop worth price"       "price amazing user"      
#[5] "explanation complex what" "easy set"                
#[7] "product best buy"         "buy priceless when"   

sent$words[-1] <- with(sent, ifelse(w1==w2, sub('\\w+ ', '',words[-1]), 
                  words[-1]))
sent$words
#[1] "just right size"          "love quality"            
#[3] "laptop worth price"       "amazing user"            
#[5] "explanation complex what" "easy set"                
#[7] "product best buy"         "priceless when"
```

Comment: This works only for first two sentences. Is it possible to extend your approach for all sentences in data frame?

Comment: @Martin I thought your expected result is the same as that I showed in the output.  Can you show the expected output.  If there is anomaly in a different example, please do update it in your post

Comment: @Martin Is it possible that your column have leading/lagging spaces?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Akrun, you helped me a lot :-)